# How would one make noise into fractal noise in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials

The cycles noise texture has a detail slider to increase the number of times the noise is layered on itself, making a fractal, however, not all textures have this slider. How would one be able to make, say, voronoi noise into fractal noise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A hacky way I can think to do this would be to create a series of Voronoi texures, and combine them in a way that each iteration is a portion of the size of the previous (in this example each iteration of the texture would be one half than the previous one). Then combine the textures using an RGB node in multiply mode to bring all of them together into a single texture:

(click on the image to enlarge)

[image]

[image]

Though I'm sure that some of the very smart folks that actually know how to write scripts, can come up with something more reasonable.